# Error when overriding updateConstaints on a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to use AutoLayout in a custom UITableViewCell programmatically.
When I try this

```
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

@implementation CustomTableViewCell

NSDictionary *_viewsDictionary;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        _nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [_nameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [_nameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:32 saturation:100 brightness:63 alpha:1]];
        [_nameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:18.0f]];
        [_nameLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_nameLabel];

        _viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_nameLabel);

        [self updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)updateConstraints {

    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_nameLabel]|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:_viewsDictionary];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:constraints];


    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_nameLabel]|"
                                                          options: 0
                                                          metrics:nil
                                                            views:_viewsDictionary];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:constraints];

    [super updateConstraints];
}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

I end up with this error:

> Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference
>   something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal.

However if I move the constraints out of updateContraints and into initWithStyle everyting works correctly (so far).  I'm worried though if I don't override updateConstraints that my UI may not update correctly in the future.

I'm not sure the error makes sense to me, since _nameLabel is added to this view.  I also don't know if I should be overriding updateConstraints at all. Can anyone explain what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making `viewsDictionary` a local variable defined and used only in `updateConstraints`.

Alternatively, don't make a `viewsDictionary` at all. Just pass the information right into the call:

```
NSArray *constraints = 
  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:
    @"H:|[lab]|" options:0 metrics:nil
    views:@{@"lab":self->_nameLabel}];
```

Comment: Thanks - that does work - do you know why?  I figure creating it once would be better then re-creating it for ecah cell.  Also I found that _viewsDictionary was already populated with one item _table before I do antyhing, which is weird because it's there even if I don't declare it.

Comment: Yes, well, it works because that's what you're supposed to do.

Comment: Ah, okay after playing around I understand now.  _viewsDictionary is being declared as a global variable (not within the brackets of @implementation) so it was being shared between the UIViewTableCell objects. So I was trying to add the label as a constraint from a different cell.  This also explains why it was already set with something in some cases.  Moving it to an instance variable fixes this and is probably better then re-creating it each time updateConstants is ran.  Thanks again.

Comment: I really don't believe that it's "probably better". This method is not going to be called very many times, and it isn't wasting any time for it to construct the dictionary when it is called. Basically, don't optimize prematurely, don't try to outsmart a macro, and don't fight the framework.